# Easiest way to configure a proxy for static Amazon S3 content and dynamic heroku content

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, dns

My mobile app consists of a dynamic portion on heroku (foo.herokuapp.com) which serves up our API and web views for some content we expose to users who don't have the app installed.  There is also of course a static landing page (http://foo.co) which is hosted on S3.

Currently, I have DNS setup to resolve foo.co to our S3 instance.  And S3 has routing rules to redirect our dynamic content (http://foo.co/some_dynamic_data/1234/) to our heroku servers.

Given it's a 3XX redirect, this results in a pretty ugly experience for the user since their browser bar is now going to reflect our heroku backend.

Question:
Is there an easy proxy service I can deploy that has special routing rules to route dynamic content to heroku and static content to S3 so that I can point foo.co DNS to the proxy and not have to expose the backend to users via redirects?

Answer (score 6):

CloudFront.

And don't say, "but I thought that was a CDN."  That's how it's marketed, but it's also a reverse proxying HTTP request router that can choose the backend based on the request path.  The caching capability can be used, or it can be disabled if you don't need/want/understand it.

Create a distribution with two origins (that's what CloudFront calls your backend servers) -- one for the bucket and one for the API endpoint.

Configure your `example.com` hostname as an alternative hostname in the distribution settings.

Create path behaviors to choose which path patterns route to which origin.  If there's an obvious choice for one of them to be the default, catching every path that's otherwise unconfigured, point the default behavior to that particular origin.

Point the DNS hostname to the CloudFront distribution.

Optional: have some SSL on your site with a free certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager, which is integrated with CloudFront.